# Using fragments with RecyclerView and autoload list

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, autoload

I'm building my first android app and I'm stacked with auotoload with scroll using in  Fragments. I have Navigation Drawer Activity as a root activity from which I call different fragments. I need my fragment to handle recycler view with autoload and scroll, i begin it as

```
public class FrontPage extends Fragment implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener{
```

Actually, any link to tutorial or example with working code would be appreciated. I found many tutorials (RSS list autoload, etc) with the similar functionality from Activity, but I need it from Fragment. Please help.